# Holder pattern and convert view

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-listview, android-view

I have learned earlier about great approach to increase performance - Holder Pattern. This is good idea to speed up UI and animation.
It is clearly why and how to use it.
I have used it a lot , but now I am little bit confused about this.
When getView method is called it has three arguments one is converView. As I undertand it is previously inflated view of list item, so the are some questions about this.

1. If it is previously inflated view, why not just to use it, return it from method, of course check to null before.
2. How does this implemented,listview class has private array or another data structure that holds all inflated views ?
3. Why this feature is not implemented in adapters ?

Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you would just use the `convertView`, you would need to get hold of your views with `findViewById()`. This is exactly what the ViewHolder pattern is trying to avoid. `findViewById()` is a surprisingly expensive method and can slow down your app, especially if you constantly call it when scrolling through lists.
2. Listviews reuse the layouts of the child items, to avoid having to inflate the same views over and over again.
3. Most adapters were already available to developers before people came up with the ViewHolder pattern. The latest new list view, `RecyclerView`, has an adapter that enforces the use of the ViewHolder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `ViewHolder holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();` at the first line of `getView`. Because `convertView` could be `null`. Try again like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHoldler holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(
                    R.layout.frag_home_gridview_item, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHoldler();
            holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.gridview_item_label);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.gridview_item_name);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHoldler) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv.setText(getItem(position));
        holder.iv.setImageResource(this.ids[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHoldler {
        ImageView iv;
        TextView tv;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Because you most likely are not using same views. Say you have a row which has a TextView in it. The convertview is one of the recycled views and it's textview may be displaying different information that it should be.
2. It does keep as many views as there are visible, once you scroll down the top view get's recycled and you come back to answer 1.
3. I don't understand, your code is from the BaseAdapter class.